# Aptana Studio 3 - Warnings when using data-role Tags of HTML 5

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, aptana

I want to use Aptana Studio 3 for developing jquery-mobile projects. Since jquery-mobile uses HTML5 I have to use tag attributes like `"data-role="header"` which is OK for HTML5.

For example:

```
<div data-role="header"></div>
```

But Aptana gives me warnings like:

> unknown attribute "data-role"

How can I fix this, or is it an Aptana Studio 3 bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It more of a missing feature than a bug.

In Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation you can define regular expression that match to errors/warnings you want to be ignored.

`.*data-role.*` should do it.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and don't think I have the RegEx correct. Tried: data-* and data-role=[\"\"]*[\"\"] both didn't work. Any suggestions as I like this and wanted to implement it

Comment: Thanks! Did change it to .*data-.* (catch all). Is the .* special syntax? or I should say the dot? +1 as it works great

Comment: Unfortunately you can't define regex filters for the HTML Tidy Validator, which is the validator that is generating these warnings.

Answer (score 41):

I performed below and it resolved the problem.

In Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation  > HTML Tidy Validator  > Attributes >> Proprietary attributes --> ignore

Comment: Confirmed for Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137

Comment: to me was working only turning off HTML Tidy Validator

Answer (score 11):

This had bugged me for months. I tried the solutions above but they didn't work. What did work for me was turning off HTML Tidy Validator in Aptana 3.2.2.

*Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Validation -> HTML*

And then turn off *HTML Tidy Validator* for build and reconciliation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to it doesnt support for this, I went through Wikipedia and their doc. So we have to bear this until plug-in comes.

Answer (score 0):

Late response but I found this thread while searching to resolve the same issue, tried the regex solution, which didn't work for me, so came up with this solution, which is at least less drastic than disabling HTML Tidy Validator:

**Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy Validator**

- Change **Attributes > Proprietary Attributes** from Warning to either Ignore or Info.

There are several other frameworks other than jQuery Mobile (Angular for example) where the use of custom attributes is common, so I don't think this is a bad thing to do, as I don't know of any browser that breaks with custom attributes, they just get ignored.

While you're changing HTML Tidy Validator, I'd also recommend removing the warning for elements with no content as often folks populate those through JavaScript. You can do so like this:

- Change **Elements > Trim Empty Elements** from Warning to either Ignore or Info.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to resolve the "unrecognized" issue for my build is: Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy Validator > Elements > Unrecognized elements > Ignore