# Aptana does not know about <main> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, aptana

I am learning HTML with the Aptana IDE  v3.6 (the latest version).

When I type in some HTML5 tags like  it remind me

> the main tag is not recognized.

Aptana does not recognize html5?
Or how should I fix that?

Comment: You mean “Aptana”, right?

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847596/aptana-studio-3-warnings-when-using-data-role-tags-of-html-5). Also, remember that the <main> tag isn't supported in any versions of IE, so either don't use it or set the relevant CSS to make it function as it should.

Comment: Sorry, I even write Apantana the first time...

Comment: I noticed that aptana told me h5 elements like <header> are not supported by chrome and IE(they are dark). But w3school says <header> is supported by Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome. That is a bug in aptana, right?

Comment: Yes, I haven't used Aptana but some of the answers in the link I posted have answers that should solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the error, you could shut off Unrecognized Elements warnings like so:

1. Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy
   Validator
2. Select HTML Tidy Validtor > Elements > Unrecognized Elements

Note, however, that without these warnings, you'll be able to type undefined tags (e.g. `<abc>`).