# Suppressing errors in Aptana

Tags: html, aptana, validationerror

Since I'm working with templates I have non-html code in my html files, which leads to errors in Aptana.

Some files are completely underlined which is pretty irritating.

I found this solution : https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Adding+custom+error+message+filters+to+the+Problems+View

(Also on another topic on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847596/aptana-studio-3-warnings-when-using-data-role-tags-of-html-5))

Which I did, adding < repeat> and < repeat * >
(without the first space, when I delete the space the word seems to disappear from stackoverflow..)

But it doesn't change a thing. I'm sure my expression is wrong, but I have no idea what it should be..

```
        <repeat group="{{ @articles }}" value="{{ @idiv }}">                
            <article class="product clearfix">
                <a href="detail/{{ @idiv.SysNumVenice }}"><img id="small" src="http://www.bekafun.com/images/01_prdarticledocs/ImagesSmall{{ @idiv.Pad_afbeelding }}" /></a>
                <h3>{{ @idiv.Omschrijving_Nld }}</h3> <!-- Omschrijving NLD -->
                <p>{{ @idiv.Verkoopprijs }}&euro; &ndash; <a href="detail/{{ @idiv.SysNumVenice }}">Details</a></p> <!--Verkoopprijs-->
            </article>      
        </repeat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the HTML Tidy Validator settings.

Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation

[image: Screenshot]

By changing unrecognized elements to Ignore I no longer get the errors/complete blocks underlined.